# Shifting the focus to the next textfield

Tags: ios

I want the focus of the textfield to shift to the next textfield as soon as 2 characters are entered in the the current textfield. I am using this code but I think the placement of return statement is causing certain problems such as: 1) in the last text field it is not restricting it to 2 characters. 2) After shifting the focus to the next textfield If I am coming back to the previous Text field then also it is allowing me to enter more than two characters. 3) Due to the addition of the "self.firstResponder = textfield in the textfieldDidBegin editing method my other Textfields are becoming unresponsive i.e not allowing me to enter any text. Here is my code for all the three methods.:-- 
  this is the code in shouldCharctersInRange method:

```
   (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
  replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  NSString * newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
  withString:string];

   if (string.length==0) {
    return YES;
  }


    if (textField == txt_mins) {
    return [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] setNumberFormat:textField newString:newString 
    IntegerLimit:5 FractionLimit:2 NumberType:2];
   }
    else if (textField == txt_units){
    return [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] setNumberFormat:textField newString:newString 
   IntegerLimit:5 FractionLimit:2 NumberType:2];
}
   // Below logic is for All 4 Modifer Textfields
   // we are restricting the user to enter only max 2 characters in modifier textfields
     and
  also automatically
   // converting each entered character to the uppercase string.
   if (textField==txt_modifier1 || textField==txt_modifier2 || textField==txt_modifier3 ||
    textField==txt_modifier4) {
    // This condition is restricting the user from entering the special characters in the
    modifier textfield.
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] 
     invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        // There are non-alphanumeric characters in the replacement string
        return NO;
    }
    //Added by Shikhar
    // dated: 18 June, 2013
    else{
        NSString *result = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
         withString:string.uppercaseString];


        // this condition is automatically transferring the focus to the next textfield as
        soon we type two characters in the\
        // the current textfield.
        textField.text = result;
        if (result.length == 2){
            [self toggleTextfield];
        }

    return NO;
   }
}
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void) toggleTextfield
{
NSInteger nextTag = self.firstResponder.tag;
nextTag += 1;
UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
if (nextTextField)
{   [nextTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

}
   and the code for textfieldDidBegin editing is this:

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


    self.firstResponder = textField;
   [textField setInputAccessoryView:tb_doneToolbar];
    txt_currentFocusedTextfield = textField;




CGRect textFieldRect =[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds 
   fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y +1.0*textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator =midline - viewRect.origin.y- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * 
 viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator =(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)* 
 viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

animatedDistance = floor(162.0 * heightFraction);

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;

viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

IF somebody can help then it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Never set firstResponder directly, use `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder`.

Comment: I am not sure where you suggested me to make the changes. Can you specify it! Thanks.

Comment: From your question "3) Due to the addition of the "self.firstResponder = textfield in the textfieldDidBegin editing method" <- wherever you did that. And it's probably not a complete fix, just a comment on that particular code.

Answer (score 1):

My code does a similar thing; the different thing is it switches textfields by next/previous buttons on the `inputAccessoryView` on the `UIKeyboard`. First you need to implement a method that returns an array of the `UITextField`s on the view controller.

```
- (NSArray *)arrayOfTextFieldsOnTheVC{

   //Return an array of all the desired textfields on the VC
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.textField1, self.textField2, nil];

}
```

At this point I am using two different methods called

```
- (void)tappedNextOnkeybardExtensionView:(KeyboardExtensionView *)keyboardExtensionView;
- (void)tappedPreviousOnkeybardExtensionView:(KeyboardExtensionView *)keyboardExtensionView;
```

`KeyboardExtensionView` is a custom `UIView`, which I am using as the `inputAccessoryView` for the keyboard. When the user taps next or previous, I am invoking the method below. You need another mechanism to invoke that method (I think you should override textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange), which iterates between the given textfields:

```
- (void)setNextTextFieldFirstResponderFromTextFieldsArray:(NSArray *)arrTextFields inForwardDirection:(BOOL)forwardDirection{

for ( int i = 0; i < [arrTextFields count] ; i ++ ){

    UITextField *tfd = [arrTextFields objectAtIndex:i];
    if ( [tfd isFirstResponder] ){

        if (i == 0 && !forwardDirection){ 
            // Tapped previous on first text field

            break;
        }

        else if (i == [arrTextFields count] - 1 && forwardDirection){ 
            //Tapped next on last text field

            break;

        }

        else if (forwardDirection){

            [[arrTextFields objectAtIndex:i+1] becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }

        else if (!forwardDirection){

            [[arrTextFields objectAtIndex:i-1] becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }

    }
}
}
```

`forwardDirection` needs to be `NO` if you want to go the previous keyboard, and `YES` if you want to switch to next. `arrTextFields` is the array of `UITextFields` on the VC, use the first method for invoking this one as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for 1st question would be

//add this code above the code where you checking for toggleTextfield

```
if(textField==txt_modifier4 && result.length ==2)
   [self resignFirstResponder]
```

Question:
  when other textFields are becoming unresponsive?

Comment: first of all where to make the change you suggested, I am not clear about it and then for your question the other tExtfields  become unresponsive as soon as I tap in one of the modifier textfields i.e after typing in those four textfields if I try to type in other text fileds they become unresponsive.

Comment: check my edited code. and about your third question : store nil in self.firstResponder when its entering in any other fields or you hide your keyboard. I am not sure about it, but it may solve your problem.

Comment: I have made this change in my didBeginEditing but it the other textfields are still unresponsive, even the previous modifier textfileds:    if (textField==txt_modifier1 || textField==txt_modifier2 || textField==txt_modifier3 || textField==txt_modifier4) {
        
        self.firstResponder  = textField ;
        
    }
    else{
        self.firstResponder = Nil;
    }   Can you tell the wrong approach that I have followed.

Comment: did it solve ur first problem ? Try out the last thing move your self.firstResponser in - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField